# How to append some .csv files with same suffix in the name with pandas

Tags: pandas, csv, append

I have 6 .csv files within the same folder:

```
file1Milan.csv
Milanfile1.csv
file2Milan.csv
Milanfile2.csv
file3Milan.csv
Milanfile3.csv
```

I need to append (one below the other) the three .csv files whose name ends with `Milan`, that is:

```
file1Milan.csv
file2Milan.csv
file3Milan.csv
```

Does anyone know how to do it in pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import os
import pandas as pd
 
df_main = pd.DataFrame()

for file in os.listdir():
    if file.endswith("Milan.csv"):
        df_temp = pd.read_csv(file)
        df_main = df_main.append(df_temp, ignore_index=True)

df_main.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using pathlib:

```
from pathlib import Path

import pandas as pd


path = "/path/to/files/"
(pd
 .concat(objs=(pd.read_csv(x) for x in Path(path).glob("*Milan.csv")), ignore_index=True)
 .to_csv(path_or_buf=f"{path}output.csv", index=False)
 )
```